# How do you use the global variables from Drupal's PHP Views module

Tags: php, drupal, module, content-management-system, view

I am using the Drupal Views module and PHP Views module. What I have set up is 5 fields which use a PHP block to call to a function I created in Drupal. The PHP code does work and displays the data I want.

There are "Available variables" which are available to the areas where PHP code can be used, in my case its for the "Output code". So for example you have $view, $handler, $static, $row etc.

I have tried to access all of them, I get a 500 internal error or sometimes I get nothing. The error log points to the "views_php/plugins/views/views_php_handler_field.inc" at line 122. I have viewed that file and the code contains the line:

```
$function($this->view, $this, $this->php_static_variable);
```

I have tried calling the code like this:

```
<?php
global $view;
print_r($view);
?>
```

Note I have tried without the global line.

How can I gain access to these variables in PHP Views? I am using Drupal 6 and the latest version of the PHP Views module which is views_php 6.x-1.x-dev.

I have called the function "get_defined_vars()" with var_dump and with or without the global keyword the variables mentioned are not available to me. I can however access variables like $user which are global in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

On views you have the preview option. I used that most of the time to test my results. Even if you get the alert box saying that you have the `500 internal error`, go to the page where that view is set up (path). You should see the output for `$view` variable. Note, the `$view`variable show's data related to the column. What I was looking for was information regarding current position (row). You need to set up this code yourself using the `$static` variable, it retains data from one row to the other so you can track where you are in your array or data position manually.

Example of how I used static to determine where I was at the current position and where I needed to be next:

```
if (!$static['isInitial']){
    /* Should only enter this condition on the first element.
     IsInitial determines this. */

    //Count the total amount of issues in Redmine right now.
    $static['totalRedmineIssues'] = count($getValue);

    $index = 0;
    $static['currentIndex'] = $index;
    $static['isInitial'] = true;

    print_r($static);

} else {
    $static['currentIndex'] = $static['currentIndex'] + 1;
    $index = $static['currentIndex'];
}
```